# Remove double quotes from a string rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a string like:

```
str= "1,2,3,4"
```

I want to remove double quotes from this string so that i will get the result like `1,2,3,4`.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please, be more specific. What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error message? Which one? Is the output not what you are expecting? What *is* the output you are expecting? What is the output you are getting? Also, please provide a better example. There are no `"` characters in your string, you should provide a more realistic example *with* `"` characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to alter the var in place:

```
str="\"1,2,3,4\""
str.gsub!('"', '')
puts str
# 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Perhaps you can share a full test case, with actual vs expected output. Similar to the answers you've received.

Comment: whats the points in using all this when you are using "puts" to show you result. str = "1,2,3,4"
puts str
# 1,2,3,4 will do same.

Answer (score 0):

@Udaykumardas

as you mention in comment of @shivam's answer that you have to pass a string in MySQL query with `IN` function.

So, you need to do simple trick with your query like below.
for example, you need to pass id's

```
ids = "1,2,3,5,6" # ids is your variable which contains ids as a string.
```

and now your query using that `ids` variable

```
Model.where("field_name IN (?)",ids.split(','))
```

you can use like this, no need to sub string or remove `"`.

Hope this will give you idea to complete your task.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing the way you have declared your String, it never contained `"`.

```
str = "1,2,3,4"
puts str
# 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: I don't want to display the result.I need this because i want to pass this `IN` clause in mysql. Like `....sh.data_source_id IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: @Udaykumardas its the Syntax! That how you declare a String in Ruby. `"` itself is not part of the String.

Comment: But what if we wanted to remove these, any way

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal to remove something, first requirement is to have it present. You cannot remove something thats not present. Syntax for declaring a string tell us to put contents between `"`s. This means anything in between is a string. In the example there is no `"` between syntactical `"`s and hence you cannot remove anything. 
If you still ask 'what if I wanted to remove syntactical `"`s too". Yes you can! There are many ways to declare a sting in Ruby. Read here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Strings_-_Creation_and_Basics#Creating_Strings_in_Ruby