# Remove double quotes from values in hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, key

```
{"user_id"=> "row[:user_id]",
 "name" => "row[:name]",
 "address" => "row[:address]"
}
```

Want to remove the double quotes in values

desired hash

```
{"user_id"=> row[:user_id],
 "name" => row[:name],
 "address" => row[:address]
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. When you ask a question, you should show what you have already tried, where you made progress and where you failed. A bit of efffort from you is needed, so we can help you.

Comment: already tried a number of things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339112/remove-double-quotes-from-a-string-rails-4        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720401/remove-double-quotes-from-string

Comment: This looks like a shoot yourself in the foot kind of problem. What are you doing to your data that broke it this way in the first place? While you can replace `"row[:user_id]"` with the result of the expression by eval'ing you shouldn't need this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. There are no double quotes in your values.

Comment: Though I can't imagine a need to do what is requested, here you go. Let `h` equal your hash. You haven't given us the hash `row`, which is needed. Suppose `row = { user_id: 3126, name: "Sherlock", address: "221B Baker St., London" }`. Then `h.transform_values { |s| eval(s) }
#=> {"user_id"=>3126, "name"=>"Sherlock", "address"=>"221B Baker St., London"}`. See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). Beware of using [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) as it potentially can create a security issue.

Comment: Where is the hash coming from and why does it have string values instead of the return values of those method calls in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this here, there are two reg-ex. `gsub` will do a global substitution.

I did it with the help of https://regex101.com/

```rb
str = '{"user_id"=> "row[:user_id]",
 "name" => "row[:name]",
 "address" => "row[:address]"
}'

re = /\"row\[:/m
subst = 'row[:'
result1 = str.gsub(re, subst)

re = /]"/m
subst = ']'
result2 = result1.gsub(re, subst)

# Print the result of the substitution
puts result2
```